# CentOS mod_fastcgi

Tags: linux, centos, mod-fastcgi

I have server with installed CentOS 6.2 with nginx and php-fpm from remi repos

httpd also installed, but when I try to install mod_fastcgi yum sais that no pachage availiable

How I can install mod_fastcgi??? Googling different sites says that command

```
yum install mod_fastcgi
```

must install this package. But yum sais:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * remi: remi-mirror.dedipower.com
196 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
No package mod_fastcgi available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 8):

There don't appear to be any official packages for `mod_fastcgi`. It seems that RedHat would prefer that you use `mod_fcgid`, but it's missing an important feature, the ability to use an external FastCGI server process (not managed by Apache) such as PHP-FPM.

From http://www.garron.me/en/linux/apache-mpm-worker-php-fpm-mysql-centos.html, I found that 
you can download unofficial `mod_fastcgi` RPMs from the RPMForge/RepoForge repository:

```
sudo rpm --import http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
sudo rpm -ivh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install mod_fastcgi
```

I have tested them lightly and they work for me.

Comment: I had some trouble using the commands as is, but this page helped: http://repoforge.org/use/
I had to download the file and then use rpm, not use rpm directly on the url for some reason.

Comment: For others coming across this, repoforge has since been [declared inactive](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge)  and the `pkgs.repofirge.org` domain has been brought down. Please use an acceptable mirror: http://mirror-status.repoforge.org/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do an install from source. Try following the instructions here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-centos-fedora-apache2-fastcgi-php-configuration.html

I've successfully used these instructions on Centos.

Answer (score -3):

install `mod_fcgid` from epel repository

```
# yum --enablerepo=epel info mod_fcgid
Available Packages
Name       : mod_fcgid
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 2.2
Release    : 11.el5
Size       : 58 k
Repo       : epel
Summary    : Apache2 module for high-performance server-side scripting
URL        : http://fastcgi.coremail.cn/
License    : GPL+
Description: mod_fcgid is a binary-compatible alternative to the Apache module mod_fastcgi.
           : mod_fcgid has a new process management strategy, which concentrates on reducing
           : the number of fastcgi servers, and kicking out corrupt fastcgi servers as soon
           : as possible.
```

Comment: mod_fcgid is a DIFFERENT package from mod_fastcgi. The question talks about mod_fastcgi which does not have an RPM package in EPEL AFAIK. See http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4385 for more details on the differences between the two.