# No package mod_fastcgi available on centos 6.8

Tags: php, fastcgi, centos6, apache2.2

I'm newbie, I'm trying to install php mod fastcgi for apache 2.2 on centos 6.8, but I got error with message: "No package mod_fastcgi available. Nothing to do".
Please help me, thank so much.

> [root@host15 ~]# yum install -y mod_fastcgi
>
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
>
> Setting up Install Process
>
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>
> - base: mirror.digistar.vn
> - epel: mirrors.digipower.vn
> - extras: mirror.digistar.vn
> - remi: mirror.upb.edu.co
> - remi-php56: mirror.upb.edu.co
> - remi-safe: mirror.upb.edu.co
> - updates: mirrors.viethosting.com
>
> 2347 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
>
> No package mod_fastcgi available.
>
> Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CentOS mod\_fastcgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005137/centos-mod-fastcgi)

Answer (score 0):

This mod_fastcgi extension is dead for years, and not available in the repositories.

You can use, instead

- **mod_fcgid**, see its [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/) and [package information](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/mod_fcgid)
- **mod_proxy_fcgi**, see its [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html) and [package information](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/mod_proxy_fcgi)

The second one is a backport from httpd 2.4 to 2.2 of the default fastcgi implementation. To use it, see the [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive.